# Meaning of ' as long as you fed him, he would be cooperative'

Tags: grammar, meaning

About the meaning of the sentence 'as long as you fed him, he would be cooperative':

(1) The clause 'as long as you fed him' is about past or present one?

(2) Depending on the above, the 'would' at the last clause is of conditional mood or

past of 'will'?

Could you kind of explain the meaning of the sentence as clarifying?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that [**as long as = provided that**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20long%20as)

Answer (score 1):

That phrase is the past tense version of "as long as you feed him, he will be cooperative."  The confusion is most likely due to the fact that it uses the indefinite 'you', which one should try to avoid.

It basically means "as long as he was fed, he was willing to cooperate."